# Webcomic Navigation Using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, image, navigation

I'm building my new webcomics home on my website and have ran smack into a wall.

Here's what I want and what I've tried.

I'm trying to have something where using JavaScript I can make only the image of the comic change so that I do not have to make a new page for every single image. I don't mind having to do extra coding work as long as I don't have hundreds of pages in my directory.

I was going to have a /First Next Prev Last/ kind of navigation but I've been so frustrated with it that I kind of scrapped that idea for now and instead am thinking of having a list of the names + link of each comic below the image and just put that into a scroll box. Kinda like how Perry Bible Fellowship works.

I've been trying to figure out if maybe an array is the way to go as I have around 30 images so far and I will be updating daily. Honestly I don't even know if Javascript is the way to go either.

I've also tried to implement [this code](http://interestingwebs.blogspot.com/2012/09/change-image-onclick-with-javascript.html
) to see if it would work and it just seems to break as soon as I try to plug in my own stuff into it. Here's an example of my javascript butcher job:

```
<script language="javascript">
function Drpepper() 
{
    document.getElementById("image").src = "/comics/1DrPepper.jpg";  
}

function Applestore() 
{
    document.getElementById("image").src = "/comics/2Applestore.jpg"; 
}
</script>

<p>
<img alt="Dr Pepper" src="1DrPepper.jpg" 
        style="height: 85px; width: 198px" id="image" /></p>
<p>
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="Dr Pepper" onclick="DrPepper()"/>   
<input id="Button2" type="button" value="Apple Store" onclick="Applestore()" /></p>
```

Is there anyway to expand this for my purposes? What I would like is to not have buttons and just use links but I can't seem to get beyond this part here where the image doesn't even load and the buttons do nothing.

Also if there is some better way of doing this using any other method other than JavaScript, I'm more than open to it, except the aforementioned making hundreds of pages.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/M2BSu/ I found this as well but I need help to fix this into my situation.

Comment: I’d recommend looking into some server-side language like PHP. Using JavaScript makes your page inaccessible to people without JavaScript enabled and some automated crawlers like Google.

Answer (score 0):

First off, consider using jQuery if you're going to go the Javascript route. Here's an example I mocked up for you:

```
// set up an array of comic images
var imgs = [
        'http://dustinland.com/dlands/dland.sxsw.jpg',
        'http://dustinland.com/dlands/dland.hipster.jpg',
        'http://dustinland.com/dlands/dland.legalize.marijuana.jpg',
        'http://dustinland.com/dlands/dland.TLDR.jpg'
    ],
    // initialize current to 0
    current = 0;

// define a function that returns the next item in the imgs array, 
// or the first if we're already at the last one
function next() {
    current++;
    if (current >= imgs.length) current = 0;
    return imgs[current];
}

// define a function to do the opposite of next()
function prev() {
    current--;
    if (current < 0) current = imgs.length - 1;
    return imgs[current];
}

// define the first image in terms of a jquery object
var comic = $('<img/>').attr('src', imgs[0]);

// append to DOM
$('#comics').append(comic);

// click the prev button, get the previous image
$('#prev').on('click', function(){
    comic.attr('src', prev());
});

// click the next button, get the next image
$('#next').on('click', function(){
    comic.attr('src', next());
});
```

See this in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/QzWV5/

This may work fine for your application, but maybe you should consider the advice of @icktoofay; using Javascript will mean, at the very least, that Google won't automatically crawl all your images. This also presents a usability problem: do you want to force your users to click through every comic in order to reach the first? It's probably best if every image were reachable via its own URL, that way, anyone who came across your comic on the web could easily link to an individual comic.

Have you considered using Tumblr, Blogger, or Wordpress?